# Flutter: Voice Detection Trigger Phrase

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, voice-recognition, voice, flutter-packages

I am currently using the [speech_to_text](https://pub.dev/packages/speech_to_text) package to add voice control to my Flutter app. This voice detection **is triggered by a button click**.

Is there any way to trigger the voice detection when the user says a certain phrase similiar to **"Hey Google"** instead of having to press the button every time?
The library itself does not provide a way to add a "standby detection" mode and continous detection is not supported. Other ideas on how to circumnavigate this additional click are also welcome.

If your answer includes a library it would be great if it is free or has a free plan. This would really boost the user experience a lot. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use this package:
https://pub.dev/packages/picovoice_flutter

They have a pretty detailed tutorial here: https://medium.com/picovoice/offline-speech-recognition-in-flutter-no-siri-no-google-and-no-its-not-speech-to-text-c960180e9239

It is not a common feature, so I am afraid you are not going to find a lot of options, but the one above should do the trick

Comment: This seems like a good solution however, it might get very very expensive in production.

Comment: I was quoted $6k per year for 1,000 users which was indeed prohibitively expensive -- but I think they're now offering a startup deal of 90% off for first year. For iOS there's now App Shortcuts with Siri which for iOS16+ could be a good option for many.